# Find a specific number in a text file and print the rest of he file from that point C

Tags: c, string, date

So I have this text file with information about things that people put in there and theres this number which represents the date of when it was posted (dd/mm/yy).

Exemple: This text file contains the results of certain football games, who won the season and where the celebration is

```
15042018 13:00
Marítimo Moreirense 1-1

15042018 14:00
Benfica Porto 0-1

16042018 13:00
Rio Ave Tondela 1-1

03052018 14:56 
Porto wins the season!

03052018 16:00
The celebration will be in Aliados
```

Now lefts imagine the today date is 03/05/2018 (which corresponds to the last date written in the file 03052018) and now I want to print the rest from there including the line where I find that date, like this:

```
03052018 14:56 
Porto wins the season!

03052018 16:00
The celebration will be in Aliados
```

My code, I trying to use `fseek()`, first I count the n bytes until I find a date that corresponds to todays date and then I go to the file passing n bytes and print the rest, but its failing:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *users_info;
    char datesearch[10];

    users_info = fopen("TDesporto.txt", "w+");
    int i=0;
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);

    struct tm *myTime = localtime(&currentTime);
    int date = myTime->tm_mday*1000000 + myTime->tm_mon*10000+10000 + myTime- >tm_year+1900; //this is is going to give the number of today's date

    while(!(strcmp(date,datesearch))){ //cicle ends when I find the number (datesearch) that is equal to todays date and will count the bytes until that point
    fscanf(users_info, "%d", datesearch);
    i++;
    }
    fseek(users_info,i,SEEK_SET);//going to n bytes into the file and print the rest

    char line[100];
    while(fgets(line, 100, users_info) != NULL)
    {
    printf("%s\n", line);    
    }

    fclose(users_info);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot, theres this part where I actually have to print it out backwards so it has to come out like this

```
03052018 16:00
The celebration will be in Aliados

03052018 14:56 
Porto wins the season!
```

Comment: `datesearch` is a char array, but you tell `scanf()` it is an `int` with `%d`. And `date` is an `int` but you try to use it in `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the date string, you could use [`strftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) like

```
time_t t=time(NULL);
struct tm *a = localtime(&t);
strftime(d, 9, "%d%m%Y", a);
```

where the `d` is the string.

In the format string used for `strftime()`, `%d`, `%m` and `%Y` stands for the day, month and year (as numbers) respectively.

You could then find the first instance of this string in the input file by using `strcmp()`.

```
char line[200], str[30];
long pos[100], ctr=0;
for(i=0; fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin); ++i)
{
    if(i%3==0) 
    {
        if(sscanf(line, "%29s", str)!=1 )
        {
            printf("\nSomething went wrong.");
            return 1;
        }
        if(strcmp(str, d)==0)
        {
            pos[ctr++]=ftell(fin)-strlen(line);
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

where `pos` is an array used to store the locations in the file (obtained using `ftell()`) from where the reading should done later on and `ctr` is used to index this array.

After finding a match, we need not check for further matches but just record the postitions from where the reading should take place. Let's do this in another loop as in

```
for(i+=1; fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin); ++i)
{
    if((i+1)%3==0)
    {
        pos[ctr++]=ftell(fin);
    }
}
```

After all the positions have been recorded, we'll use them to display the output

```
for(i=ctr-1; i>=0; --i)
{
    fseek(fin, pos[i], 0);
    for(int j=0; j<2; ++j)
    {
        if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin)==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

And as was said, `date` in your program is an `int` and cannot be used as argument of `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `strcomp` to compare an `int` (`date`) with a string (`datesearch`). Converting `date` to a character string should fix the issue, though it may be easier to convert `datesearch` to an `int` using `atoi` to avoid needing to deal with string length and terminal bytes.

Note also that the leading 0s in `datesearch` will not be reflected in the integer representation of `date`. This also suggests using `atoi`, as this will eliminate the leading 0s when converting from string to `int`.